# Set up Google Tag Manager tag exceptions based off of user/traffic source

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a Google Tag Manager event that is currently firing for all pages, and so all users. Is there a way to add a custom exception for this event to trigger depending on where the user has come from (traffic source)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is indeed possible. The problem, however, is that the source information is typically not saved after the first pageview. So you'll have to save it.

First, make a custom HTML tag that would fire on every page, and set their document.referrer in a 30-minute cookie if that cookie doesn't exist.

Now just use that cookie's value via a CJS variable, or just use it directly in your blocker.